# Single line command to cat last file in ls -lrt output?

Tags: ls, cat

System log files are serialized and I use `ls -lrt` to show me the most recent file. I then `cat` that file. This requires typing a long serial number each time.

How can I `cat` the last file appearing in my `ls -lrt` output in one command?

I'm using cygwin and the the output from `ls -lrt foobar_job*` look like this:

-

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 zundarz Domain Users   1133 Jul 31 16:54 foobar_job4855125.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 zundarz Domain Users   1256 Jul 31 17:10 foobar_job4855127.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 zundarz Domain Users   1389 Aug 11 10:20 foobar_job4887829.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 zundarz Domain Users   1228 Aug 11 10:39 foobar_job4887834.log
```

Comment: What is the output of a `ls -lrt`? The date format could be important.

Comment: It's running bash.

Comment: I don't think you need the `-l` flag for `ls`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're going to just `cat` a newest file in one command you don't really need `-l` option. On `Linux` and `Cygwin` you can use `-1` option and make parsing much easier:

```
$ cat "$(ls -1rt | tail -n1)"
```

`-1` should be very portable, it's specified in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/ls.html).

Also keep in mind that [parsing `ls` output has its drawbacks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

**EDIT:**

As correctly noted in a [comment by don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223300/single-line-command-to-cat-last-file-in-ls-lrt-output/223305?noredirect=1#comment379463_223305) you don't even need `-1`:

```
 $ cat "$(ls -rt | tail -n1)"
```

Comment: '-1' is really clever.

Comment: @Minix - not really, it's not needed in this case. Per the same standard this answer links to:  _The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output; the exceptions are to terminals or when one of the -C, -m, or -x options is specified_. So in this case, it's already one entry per line, run `ls | cat` to see how it works...

Comment: @don_crissti: you're right, I added edit to my answer. Thx!

Comment: @don_crissti Even more clever! Guess I should really read the man pages more.

Answer (score 2):

This method doesn't score highly in terms of correctness but should work in most cases: `cat "$(ls -1t | head -n1)"`

Answer (score 1):

Tried it on my system and:

```
~$ cat "$(ls -lrt | tail -n 1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f9-)"
```

worked.

```
ls -lrt
```

Gives the files ordered by their modification time (`-t`) in reverse order (`-r`).

```
tail -n 1
```

Gives you the last line of the output.

```
tr -s ''
```

Removes the repeat spaces in the line.

```
cut -d ' ' -f9-
```

Cuts the line on every space and gives you the 9th field, which is the file name. Adding `-` to the `-f9` also gives all following fields, which is important for filenames containing spaces.

#### Alias

If you want to use the command as an alias, you have to escape the `"` characters.

That `"`'s in the command are necessary, because files can have spaces, which would be interpreted as more than one file by the `cat` command, if not enclosed by `"`'s.

It is also necessary to escape the `$` sign. Otherwise the command inside `$(...)` would be executed once, when setting the alias and not every time the alias is called afterwards.

```
alias catrec="cat \"\$(ls -lrt | tail -n 1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f9-)\""
```

Comment: I tried to make alias out of it: `alias catrec=' <your command> '`, but it's not parsed correctly, it returns an error *`-f9)"` not found*. BTW, you command is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: @Konrad That is because I also `'` in my command. I will edit my answer to give a suitable solution.

Answer (score -1):

Bash one-liner (provided your filenames do not contain spaces):

```
cat $(ls -lrt | tail -1 | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev)
```

Explanation:

```
tail -1        # get last line of your ls
rev            # reverse characters order
cut -d" " -f1  # take first field using space as a separator
```

So the `rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev` thing is a trick to be sure to get the last space-separated word without having to provide a platform dependent field number of character offset.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer but it won't work with a file that has a whitespace in name, try it: `echo bb > "awesome file" && cat $(ls -lrt | tail -1 | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev)`

Comment: I'm well aware of that, I should write it down.

Comment: I think that you should fix your answer